# What is the meaning of "(7)" in "cmake-env-variables(7)" in CMake documentation?

Tags: cmake

I'm learning CMake and reading its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/). And I noticed that every documentation entry of CMake ends with `(1)` or `(7)`.

[image: cmake doc]

What is it? Why is it `(1)` or `(7)`?

Comment: They’re man page categories. 1 is user commands, 7 misc

Comment: OK, thanks. I really don't know that because I have little programming experience in UNIX programming.